# Micro-controller 3.3v power supply from 115v/230v AC

Tags: power-supply

I'd like to build a power supply for a micro-controller - likely 3.3VDC using 'household' current (ideally same design for either 115VAC or 230VAC). From a safety standpoint, I'd like to come up with an efficient, low-heat approach.

Have done quite a bit of work from the micro-controller *down*, but have no experience with power supplies...

Can anyone point to a schematic or two to help jumpstart my learning process?

What does the list of major *gotchas* look like?

Comment: Due to safety concerns, regulations and complexity an offline AC/DC supply is not a good starting project for someone with no power supply experience.  It's best done by offline power specialists.  You're better off buying and off the shelf supply.

Comment: You can buy small fully encapsulated, isolated mains to 3v3 supply modules.  At a yet simpler level you can use a quality USB charger followed by another regulator.

Comment: It's not an offline supply I'm seeking to build; it's an on-board one. Any ideas?